# Tailwind bg opacity

Tags: css, background, opacity, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I was curious about the CSS behind tailwinds bg opacity. I could only find 'opacity' in pure CSS but that affects everything rather than just the background. Could somebody please explain this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Tailwinds background opacity](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-opacity) affects variable which is used in color parameter. Tailwind uses `rgba(red, green, blue, opacity)` where the last parameter is color opacity.

For example `.bg-black` looks like this:

```css
.bg-black {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```

and `bg-opacity-50` looks like this:

```css
.bg-opacity-50 {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 0.5;
}
```

it overloads `--tw-bg-opacity` variable and results into the:

```css
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
```

Comment: Do you the pros of this approach rather than not setting `--tw-bg-opacity` in `.bg-black` and using a default value in `background-color`, cause that would make the css not dependant on the declaration order

Answer (score 3):

See [Here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color) in the tailwind docs. The second number indicates the opacity.

```
<button class="bg-sky-500/100 ..."></button>
<button class="bg-sky-500/75 ..."></button>
<button class="bg-sky-500/50 ..."></button>
```

Comment: Holy 0787, how could I miss that!!

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for adding the background opacity in Tailwind CSS version 3.3.3 is [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#changing-the-opacity).
You simply have to state the color and then the opacity,

```
<button class="bg-sky-500/100 ..."></button>
```

and if you are using arbitrary values for opacity,

```
<div class="bg-sky-500/[.06] ..."></div>
```

I have ReactJS project with Tailwind v3.3.3 and adding the opacity according to the above mentioned way to extended colours didn't work for me and I did some digging and found the solution.

I added my colours to a file called `colorPalette.js` as shown below:

```
export const darkThemeColorPalette = {
  "--primary-50": "7, 28, 51", // RGB values of the color
  // Rest of the colours should be added here with the above format
};
```

Then in `tailwind.config.js`,

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: {
          50: "rgba(var(--primary-50))",
          // ADD THE REST OF THE COLORS HERE
        },  
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

As you can see the colours are mentioned in `rgba()` format. If you haven't specified an opacity, by default this will consider 1 as opacity and when you have specified an opacity it will consider the mentioned value as the opacity.

Then I injected the colours to the root div as shown below:

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import { darkThemeColorPalette } from "./constants/common/colorPalette";
import Routes from "./Routes";

const App = () => (
  <div style={darkThemeColorPalette} className="">
    <Router>
      <Routes />
    </Router>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding :D

Answer (score 0):

For those who doesn't want to append to their `tailwind.config.css`:

```
<div className="bg-[rgb(255,0,0)]/50">
```

A common pitfall is putting spaces in between the commas or inside the brackets.